# My discord bot won't respond when a meme is flagged as NSFW

Tags: json, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a discord bot with a command that gets a random reddit post and i tried adding an NSFW filter but now if anything is flagged then it responds with "The application did not respond"

It's supposed to grab a new meme and post it but i responds with "The application did not respond"

```
@client.tree.command(name='random-reddit-meme', description='when asking for a specific subreddit please just write the name of the subreddit without \"r/\"')
async def random_reddit_meme(interaction: discord.Interaction, subreddit: str=None):
    def getsub(subreddit):
        if subreddit == None:
            r = requests.get('https://meme-api.com/gimme/dankmemes')
            subreddit = 'dankmemes'
        else:
            r = requests.get(f'https://meme-api.com/gimme/{subreddit}')
        
        res = r.json()
        author = res['author']
        title = res['title']
        url = res['postLink']
        
        return r, subreddit, author, title, url
    re, subreddit, author, title, url = getsub(subreddit)
    res = re.json()
    nsfw = bool(res['nsfw'])

    def embedmeme(res, subreddit, author, title, url):
        em = discord.Embed(url=url)
        em.set_image(url=res['url'])
        em.add_field(name='Meme', value=f'Sent from: r/{subreddit} by the user: {author} \n\n {title}')

        return em

    if not nsfw:
        print(f'NSFW: {nsfw}')
        em = embedmeme(res, subreddit, author, title, url)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=em)
    else:
        print('Meme flagged as NSFW retrying command')
        re, subreddit, author, title, url = getsub(subreddit)
        res = re.json()
        nsfw = bool(res['nsfw'])
        em = embedmeme(res, subreddit, author, title, url)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=em)
```

Comment: Try to use `interaction.response.defer()` at the start and see if it works. [API Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=defer#discord.InteractionResponse.defer)

Answer (score 0):

### The Issue

You are receiving "The application did not respond" because you are not responding to the interaction passed to the client within 3 seconds. To combat this, you need to defer the interaction, do the long operation, then edit the original response or follow up after.

```py
await interaction.response.defer()
await some_long_operation()
await interaction.followup.send('Done!')
```

### Fixing The Issue

In your case, the `requests.get` method could be causing the command to take longer than 3 seconds. At times, the command may make multiple requests until the response is not an NSFW Reddit post, this takes time. `requests` is a blocking library, so you should also not be using it with your async code. [Discord.py uses](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/requirements.txt#L1) [`aiohttp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/), which means it is already installed on your system. You should switch to it in your code to avoid future issues similar to this one.

To revise the example you provided, you can add a bot variable to your `commands.Bot` instance to have an [`aiohttp.ClientSession`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientSession) instance set as an attribute. This will allow you to use it in your commands easily.

```py
from typing import Optional
import aiohttp
import asyncio

import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=discord.Intents.default())

@bot.tree.command(name='random-reddit-meme', description='...')
async def random_reddit_meme(interaction: discord.Interaction, subreddit: Optional[str] = None):
    # Defer the interaction
    await interaction.response.defer()
    
    # Uses the "subreddit" and replaces "r/..." to "..." or defaults to 
    # 'dankmemes'
    selected_subreddit = (subreddit and subreddit.replace('r/', '')) or 'dankmemes'

    # We do not want to display an NSFW meme to the user, so while NSFW
    # is true, we want to get a new meme.
    nsfw = True
    while nsfw:
        async with bot.session.get(f'https://meme-api.com/gimme/{selected_subreddit}') as response:
            data = await response.json()

        nsfw = res['nsfw']

    embed = discord.Embed(url=url, title=data['title'])
    embed.set_image(url=data['url'])
    embed.add_field(name='Meme', value=f'Sent from: r/{subreddit} by the user: {data["author"]}')

    await interaction.followup.send(embed=embed)

# Because we need to set a bot variable (session), we need to use a main
# function instead of running normally with "bot.run()"
async def main():
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession()

    # Set the session variable on our bot
    bot.session = session

    # Use the async context managers for bot and session
    async with bot, session:
        await bot.start('bot token')

asyncio.run(main())
```

Great. The application will now automatically respond to the interaction then followup later, as well as use `aiohttp` instead of `requests` to remain async!